# Changing the place of function calls breaks the communication on uart

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller

Today I've encoundered very confusing problem. I was sending data from pc to MCU and vice versa over UART.
I was using interrupts.
I have two different versions of code. They looks almost the same, but one of them is not working properly - data is not sent back to pc (first version works ok). I have no idea why, but I would like to know in order to detect such issuse in the future much faster.

Full version of code -> https://gitlab.com/bielu000/stm32-libopencm3
Branches:

- uart_not_working_version
- uart_working_version

Important files are in: src/app/src.

I can leave it like it is in working version but I want to understand the nature of that problem in order to avoid such issues in the future.

The keys differences between those two versions:

- version 1 -> I'm constantly calling (from loop in main) function server_check(), which checks whether 64kb was already received by MCU, if so then those bytes are copied to write_buffer and then sent back to pc
- version 2 -> I don't use function server_check, because it's functionality is moved to server_run, which is called once from main, and then uses it's own loop to never stops, and in that loop there is almost excatly the same code like in function server_check from version 1.

MCU: STM32F103
I'm using g++ 8.2

Compliation flags:

> set(COMPILER_CXX_FLAGS "-fno-use-cxa-atexit -O1 -fno-exceptions -g")

> set(COMPILER_FLAGS "-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -DNDEBUG -Wall
> -Werror -g")

How it is possible that changing the place of functions calls breaks MCU functionality in general?

Version 1.
//main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  //init clock etc

  server_init();
  server_run();

  while(true)
  {
    server_check();
  }
}
```

//server.cpp

```
extern "C" {
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/usart.h> 
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
  #include <libopencm3/cm3/nvic.h>
}

#include <server.hpp>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ring_buffer.hpp>
#include <target.h>

static uint8_t w_buffer[1024]; // write buffer
static uint8_t r_buffer[1024]; // read buffer

utils::containers::RingBuffer write_rb{w_buffer, sizeof(w_buffer)};
utils::containers::RingBuffer read_rb{r_buffer, sizeof(r_buffer)};

static void sendData()
{
  if (write_rb.capacity() != 0)
  {
    usart_send(USART1, write_rb.read());
    usart_enable_tx_interrupt(USART1);
  }
  else 
  {
    usart_disable_tx_interrupt(USART1);
  }
}

static void readData()
{
  auto data = usart_recv(USART1);
  read_rb.write(static_cast<uint8_t>(data));

  // usart_enable_rx_interrupt(USART1);
}

void server_init()
{
  //RCC
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_USART1);

  //GPIO
  gpio_set_mode(GPIO_BANK_USART1_TX, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50_MHZ, 
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_PUSHPULL, GPIO_USART1_TX);

  gpio_set_mode(GPIO_BANK_USART1_RX, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, 
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_OPENDRAIN, GPIO_USART1_RX);

  //USART
  usart_set_mode(USART1, USART_MODE_TX_RX);
  usart_set_baudrate(USART1, 9600);
  usart_set_parity(USART1, USART_PARITY_NONE);
  usart_set_databits(USART1, 8);
  usart_set_stopbits(USART1, 1);
  usart_set_flow_control(USART1, USART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
  usart_enable_rx_interrupt(USART1);

  //ISR
  nvic_enable_irq(NVIC_USART1_IRQ);
  
  //Enable 
  usart_enable(USART1);
}


void server_run()
{
}

void server_check()
{
    if (read_rb.capacity() == 64)
    {
      while (read_rb.capacity() != 0)
      {
        write_rb.write(read_rb.read());
      }

      sendData();
    }
}

void usart1_isr()
{
  if (usart_get_flag(USART1, USART_FLAG_TXE) != 0) 
  {
    sendData();
  }

  if (usart_get_flag(USART1, USART_FLAG_RXNE) != 0) // when data is ready to read
  {
    readData(); 
  }
}
```

Version 2

```
main.cpp
int main()
{
  //init clock etc

  server_init();
  server_run();

  while(true)
  {

  }
}

server.cpp

extern "C" {
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/usart.h> 
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
  #include <libopencm3/cm3/nvic.h>
}

#include <server.hpp>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ring_buffer.hpp>
#include <Os.hpp>
#include <target.h>

/**
 * 
 *  | MSG_TYPE | |
 * 
 */

static uint8_t w_buffer[1024]; // write buffer
static uint8_t r_buffer[1024]; // read buffer

utils::containers::RingBuffer write_rb{w_buffer, sizeof(w_buffer)};
utils::containers::RingBuffer read_rb{r_buffer, sizeof(r_buffer)};

static void sendData()
{
  if (write_rb.capacity() != 0)
  {
    usart_send(USART1, write_rb.read());
    usart_enable_tx_interrupt(USART1);
  }
  else 
  {
    usart_disable_tx_interrupt(USART1);
  }
}

static void readData()
{
  auto data = usart_recv(USART1);
  read_rb.write(static_cast<uint8_t>(data));

  // usart_enable_rx_interrupt(USART1);
}

void server_init()
{
  //RCC
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_USART1);

  //GPIO
  gpio_set_mode(GPIO_BANK_USART1_TX, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50_MHZ, 
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_PUSHPULL, GPIO_USART1_TX);

  gpio_set_mode(GPIO_BANK_USART1_RX, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, 
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_OPENDRAIN, GPIO_USART1_RX);

  //USART
  usart_set_mode(USART1, USART_MODE_TX_RX);
  usart_set_baudrate(USART1, 9600);
  usart_set_parity(USART1, USART_PARITY_NONE);
  usart_set_databits(USART1, 8);
  usart_set_stopbits(USART1, 1);
  usart_set_flow_control(USART1, USART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
  usart_enable_rx_interrupt(USART1);

  //ISR
  nvic_enable_irq(NVIC_USART1_IRQ);
  
  //Enable 
  usart_enable(USART1);



}


void server_run()
{
  while(true)
  {
    if (read_rb.capacity() == 64)
    {
      while (read_rb.capacity() != 0)
      {
        write_rb.write(read_rb.read());
      }

      sendData();
    }
  }
  
}

void server_check()
{
 
}

void usart1_isr()
{
  if (usart_get_flag(USART1, USART_FLAG_TXE) != 0) 
  {
    sendData();
  }

  if (usart_get_flag(USART1, USART_FLAG_RXNE) != 0) // when data is ready to read
  {
    readData(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the following tips with the Version 2 code:

- remove the `while(true)` from the `main()` function
- replace the `==64` with `>=64` to make sure that the buffer is processed even if one value is skipped and the capacity becomes 65: `if (read_rb.capacity() >= 64)`

Also, it should be avoided putting infinite loops in other functions except main.

Comment: I tried to add changes that you suggested but it didn't help. Here is full version of code: https://gitlab.com/bielu000/stm32-libopencm3 branches: uart_not_working_version and uart_working_version. Important files are in src/app/src. I can leave it like it is, but I want to understand the nature of that problem.

Comment: I found something:
- -O0 - works 
- -O1 - does not work

CMAKEBUILDTYPE -> Debug && -O0 -> works 
CMAKEBUILDTYPE -> Release && -O0 -> does not work